# react native firebase async await parellel with promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, es6-promise

```
import fire from '../config/fire';
const db = fire.firestore();
class InitialDb extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schools: '',
      students: '',
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { size: schools } = await db.collection('schools').get();
    const { size: students } = await db.collection('students').get();

    this.setState({ schools, students});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        {/* <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor='#1b75ce' />
        <HC title='Dashboard' /> */}
        <BackButton />
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, marginBottom: 20 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={styles.widthstyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                
                  <Card>
                    <CardItem>
                      <Body>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                          <Image
                            style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                            source={require('../assets/schools.png')}
                          />
                          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            Schools:{this.state.schools}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                  </Card>
                
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.widthstyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                
                  <Card>
                    <CardItem>
                      <Body>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                          <Image
                            style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                            source={require('../assets/asd.png')}
                          />
                          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            Students:{this.state.students}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                  </Card>
                
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
            //   style={styles.basic1Style}
          >
            <View style={styles.widthstyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Card>
                  <CardItem>
                    <Body>
                      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Image
                          style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                          source={require('../assets/def.png')}
                        />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                          Office:50
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </Body>
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.widthstyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Card>
                  <CardItem>
                    <Body>
                      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <Image
                          style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                          source={require('../assets/abc.png')}
                        />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Attended:50</Text>
                      </View>
                    </Body>
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        {/* <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Swipe from left to right for menu
          </Text> */}
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 5 }}>
            Search
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Form style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Item style={{ paddingLeft: 20, width: '40%' }}>
              <Label style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Division</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item style={{ paddingLeft: 20, width: '40%' }}>
              <Label style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Area</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <Item style={{ paddingLeft: 20, width: '40%' }}>
              <Label style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Gang</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item
              style={{
                borderBottomColor: 'white',
              }}
            >
              <Button info style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>
                <Text> Search </Text>
              </Button>
            </Item>
          </View>
        </Form>

        {/*<View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 3, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
            <MapView
              initialRegion={{
                latitude: 12.93092,
                longitude: 77.602156,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
              }}
              style={styles.mapStyle}
            ></MapView>
          </View>
         */}
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  basic1Style: {
    // flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  widthstyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 3,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

export default InitialDb;
```

**This code above is working synchronously and also in series manner. I want this to be in async and await because this is freezing the UI. And also it should update the all 2 state objects after getting the size of all those 2 firestore collections using promise.all.
Here I have updated the code Please check it again **

Answer (score 1):

#### PROBLEM

The problem here is basically your firebase is initializing on every `hot-module` reload. You only need to initialize once per App.

So basically, you could wrap your firebase initialization with `try-catch` and swallow the error.

```
try {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    /** config here **/
  });
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Dear sir, But i need the size of those collections as how i have explained in my function

Comment: That what it is, isn't it? Did you try the code above?

Comment: I Got the size sir but it is still freezing the UI

Comment: Could you post your whole component code? It should work. Seems like you're rendering infinitely.

Comment: Looks good to me. Can you create a snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/)? Asynchronous functions doesn't block the UI.
I don't think there is an issue with your `asynchronous function`.

Comment: But what about the firestore API data sir?

Comment: Are you sure? Comment out your asynchronous function and see if the problem still persists?

Comment: Sir, I'm not getting any problem in the UI like Freeziiing the UI, if i comment out the "async componentDidMount" function.

Comment: There is something wrong with your firebase API then. Create a snack and can figure it out.

Comment: Okay in a while i'll do that

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@07rakshi/90c4ee hi sir this is my snack

Comment: Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@sapien/90c4ee) out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221130/discussion-between-manoj-h-m-and-prateek-thapa).

Comment: The problem is resolved. You could check my snack and also I've updated my code above.

Comment: Sir But that is for very less number of collection count, Here we have large number of collections, I mean more than 200 documents in a collection, and that is freezing the UI

Comment: Create a snack first. API calls can't freeze the UI. They don't block the `UI Thread`.
If your API calls are late, just add a loader to the screen and wait until the data arrives.

Comment: Sir I have already created the snack and given You the link https://snack.expo.io/@07rakshi/supportive-tortilla

Comment: Check this snack :- https://snack.expo.io/@sapien/90c4ee

Comment: No Sir... same Like before. I did that snack only... I'm getting the size but after some 30 seconds. And till that time UI is completely freezed